# What are advantages / disadvantages when setting data in controllers so to make that available in models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, agile

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know what *advantages* / *disadvantages* the following code has or could have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user_for_models

  private

  def set_current_user_for_models
    User.current_user = User.find(...) # Find the user from cookies.
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :current_user

  private

  def some_method(user)
    if User.current_user == user
      # Make a thing...
    else
      # Make another thing...
    end
  end
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_method(user)
    if User.current_user == user
      # Make a thing...
    else
      # Make another thing...
    end
  end
end
```

Have you some advice? How would you improve the code?

### Updated after the @tokland comment on the @Wawa Loo answer

*Note*: the main difference is that `User.current_user` should be updated also in `after_find`, `after_create`, `...` model callbacks. Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :current_user

  after_initialize :some_method

  private

  def some_method
    if User.current_user == self
      # Make a thing...
    else
      # Make another thing...
    end
  end
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :some_method

  private

  def some_method
    if User.current_user == self.user
      # Make a thing...
    else
      # Make another thing...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: a model should know about the current user only if you send it as argument to methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I recommend you to read through [this rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) for an overview on Rails development.

Comment: However, I heard that an approach such that used in the question could "break" the MVC pattern in some way. What do you think about?

Comment: It's hard to give comments. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish here. My suggest is to look open-source RoR project to mimic first then roll your own. For me, the M dealt with database, the C is the middle man between M and V...hope it helps.

Comment: "For me, the M dealt with database, the C is the middle man between M and V..." is smart... eheh. I think that, in some way, the `ApplicationController` is loaded before models and for this the above code could works... hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing the `current_user` in your `session`, not as an accessor for the class User. The method `set_current_user_for_models` will be executed with each request. How does it find the user anyway - `User.find(...)`?

Comment: I do not use the `session` because it is not available in model classes. Anyway, it finds the user from `cookies`.

Comment: @user12882: Send `current_user` as argument to methods, setting it in the model is conceptually terrible (even if it works).

Comment: @tokland - I do not "send `current_user` as argument to methods" because I can not pass the `current_user` parameter to callback methods. I updated the question.

Comment: @user12882: I feel your pain, but then you shouldn't create callbacks whose execution depend on current_user. You can always create a method to be called from places (controllers, etc) where the current_user is known.

Comment: @Wawa Loo - Why "shouldn't I create callbacks whose execution depend on current_user"? what are pitfalls?

Comment: @user12882: You should not set current_user in a model because you could be using that model from two different places, in each place being the current_user different.

Comment: @user12882: a model is a representation of data in your application. A user is the current or not is a controller matter.